# Итератор по связанным массивам с преобразованием типа

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Вопрос касается реализации итератора для математического вектора из комплексных чисел. При этом сами числа хранятся в двух отдельных массивах (действительные и мнимые части отдельно).

К примеру рассмотрим следующий класс, описывающий вектор размерности `size`:

```
class Vector{
  unsigned int size;//размер вектора
  double* real;//массив, хранящий действительную часть
  double* imag;//массив, хранящий мнимую часть
};
```

Требуется написать итератор для объекта `Vector`, при этом он должен возвращать указатель типа `std::complex<double>`.

Чтобы лучше понять что именно я хочу сделать, приведу пример оператора доступа к элементу `i`:

```
std::complex<double> Vector::operator[](unsigned int i) const{
  return std::complex<double>(real[i],imag[i]);
}
```

С константным доступом никаких проблем нет. Однако как реализовать доступ по ссылке в данном случае? В конечном варианте хотелось бы получить что-то подобное:

```
Vector vec();
for(auto it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); it++){
  *it=std::complex<double>(1.,2.);
}
```

Т.е. вопрос состоит в следующем:

1. Как написать итератор по двум связанным массивам, при этом он должен возвращать указатель на объект типа `std::complex<double>`.
2. Как через указатель на этот объект можно изменить массивы `real` и `imag`.

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь!

PS: Как вариант вариант реализации, одно время применял следующее:

```
class Vector{
  typedef std::complex<double&> element;
  typedef std::vector<element> vector;
  typedef vector::iterator iterator;
public:
  Vector(unsigned int size);
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
private:
  unsigned int size;//размер вектора
  double* real;//массив, хранящий действительную часть
  double* imag;//массив, хранящий мнимую часть
  vector array;
};

Vector::Vector(unsigned int size):size(size){
  real=new double [size];
  imag=new double [size];

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++){
    real[i]=0.;
    imag[i]=0.;
    element a(real[i],imag[i]);
    array.push_back(a);
  }
}

Vector::iterator Vector::begin(){
  return array.begin();
}

Vector::iterator Vector::end(){
  return array.end();
}
```

т.е. доступ к элементам осуществлялся через дублирующий контейнер ссылок. Разумеется такой подход как говорится "через одно место". В частности возникают большие проблемы с конструктором копирования, векторы становятся завязанными сами на себя и прочее.

Ищу правильное и эллегантное решение!

Comment: По идее, нужно сделать что-то наподобие того, как работает итератор в `vector<bool>`.

Comment: Иметь два отдельных массива с действительными и мнимыми частями это принципиально? Не понятно почему их по отдельности в структуре не хранить?

Comment: @Cerbo: В данном случае принципиально. Я использую стороннюю библиотеку для работы с матрицами. И в частности операция умножения матрицы на вектор определена только для массива чисел `double`. Т.е. если число комплексное сначала происходит умножение действительной, затем мнимой части. Если же использовать внутри `Vector` структуру, например ту же `std::complex<double>`, придется при каждом умножении сначала переводить `N` объектов `std::complex[1][1]` в два массива `double[N]` и затем в обратном порядке. Что разумеется критически влияет на скорость работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой код должен работать (пробовал в Visual Studio 2013 и в [свежем gcc](http://ideone.com/e0mPtv)):

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class Vector
{
public:
    class iterator;
    // ссылка на пару элементов по индексу
    class reference
    {
        friend class Vector::iterator;
        Vector& vector;
        size_t i;
        reference(Vector& vector, size_t i) : vector(vector), i(i) {}
    public:
        // ведёт себя как complex<double>
        operator std::complex<double>() const
        {
            return std::complex<double>(vector.real[i], vector.imag[i]);
        }

        // и умеет присваивать complex<double> в себя
        reference& operator=(const std::complex<double>& x)
        {
            vector.real[i] = x.real();
            vector.imag[i] = x.imag();
            return *this;
        }
        reference& operator=(const reference& x)
        {
            vector.real[i] = x.vector.real[x.i];
            vector.imag[i] = x.vector.imag[x.i];
            return *this;
        }
    };

    class iterator
    {
        friend class Vector;
        Vector& vector;
        size_t i;
    public:
        iterator(Vector& vector, size_t i) : vector(vector), i(i) {}
        reference operator*() { return reference(vector, i); }
        iterator& operator++() { i++; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { auto ret = *this; i++; return ret; }
        iterator(const iterator& r) : vector(r.vector), i(r.i) { }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other)
        {
            return &vector == &other.vector && i == other.i;
        }
        bool operator != (const iterator& other)
        {
            return &vector != &other.vector || i != other.i;
        }
    };

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(*this, 0);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(*this, size);
    }

    // добавьте конструкторов по вкусу    
    Vector(double* r, double* i, size_t size) : real(r), imag(i), size(size) {}

private:
    size_t size;//размер вектора
    double* real;//массив, хранящий действительную часть
    double* imag;//массив, хранящий мнимую часть
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Vector::reference& r)
{
    return os << static_cast<std::complex<double>>(r);
}
```

Тестовая функция:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double r[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    double i[] = { 0.0, 2.0 };
    Vector vec(r, i, 2);
    for (auto val : vec)
        std::cout << val;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Для порядка, стоит добавить ещё и `const_reference` и `const_iterator`. Иначе `const`-объекты класса не будут работать.

```
class const_iterator;
class const_reference
{
    friend class Vector;
    friend class Vector::const_iterator;
    const Vector& vector;
    size_t i;
    const_reference(const Vector& vector, size_t i) : vector(vector), i(i) {}
public:
    // ведёт себя как complex<double>
    operator std::complex<double>() const
    {
        return std::complex<double>(vector.real[i], vector.imag[i]);
    }
};

class const_iterator
{
    friend class Vector;
    const Vector& vector;
    size_t i;
public:
    const_iterator(const Vector& vector, size_t i) : vector(vector), i(i) {}
    const_reference operator*() { return const_reference(vector, i); }
    const_iterator& operator++() { i++; return *this; }
    const_iterator operator++(int) { auto ret = *this; i++; return ret; }
    const_iterator(const const_iterator& r) : vector(r.vector), i(r.i) { }
    bool operator == (const const_iterator& other)
    {
        return &vector == &other.vector && i == other.i;
    }
    bool operator != (const const_iterator& other)
    {
        return &vector != &other.vector || i != other.i;
    }
};

const_iterator begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, 0);
}

const_iterator end() const
{
    return const_iterator(*this, size);
}
```

Ну и ещё индексацию:

```
reference operator[] (size_t idx)
{
    return reference(*this, idx);
}

const_reference operator[] (size_t idx) const
{
    return const_reference(*this, idx);
}
```

И форматированный вывод:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Vector::const_reference& r)
{
    return os << static_cast<std::complex<double>>(r);
}
```

Comment: @QuantumNik: Проверил, теперь компилируется.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как только наберу достаточно рейтинга обязательно поставлю вам плюсик) Сейчас попытаюсь поделать более сложные тесты. Вообще итератор нужен мне для написания интерфейса к `boost::odeint`. Если интересно, могу поделиться результатами.

Comment: @QuantumNik: Конечно! А что именно понадобилось, какой сценарий? Если у них не хватает функциональности, имеет смысл написать авторам и проложить код — пусть они включат в свежую версию своего пакета.

Comment: Как вы, кстати, считаете, оптимален ли ваш подход? Я имею в виду реализацию через вложенные классы. Насколько это "безопасно", какие-то противопоказания для использования данного подхода? Что делать в случае, если нет прямого доступа к классу, например при использовании сторонней библиотеки для описания вектора, в которой нет встроенного итератора?

Comment: @QuantumNik: Таким подходом пользуется, например, `std::vector<bool>` (у него биты упакованы в слово). Так что это в общем устоявшийся метод решения такой задачи.

Comment: Касательно `odeint` - я не претендую на добавление какой-то новой функциональности к пакету. Меня интересует чисто математическая часть. Задача состоит в обобщенном применении решения дифференциальных уравнений для векторов. К примеру для решения временного уравнения шредингера d Psi[t] / dt= - (0,1)*H* Psi[t]. Здесь Psi[t] - как раз вектор, о котором мы говорим. H - какой-то оператор, который можно представить в виде матрицы. Раздельный доступ к элементам вектора сделан как раз для оптимизации умножения матрицы на вектор.

Comment: @QuantumNik: Ну, если в пакете есть псевдомассивы, то почему бы им не иметь свой итератор? В общем-то функциональность очевидная.

Comment: @QuantumNik: Ого, у вас так серьёзная физика. Удачи вам!

Comment: Касательно псевдомассивов - у `boost::odeint` уже есть механизм добавления новых типов. И он как раз включает в себя применение итератора к заданному типу) Так что вряд ли имеет смысл писать какие-то дополнения к `odeint`-у, тут уж если хочешь использовать новый тип в библиотке - изволь добавить требуемые для нее свойства (в данном случае итератор в частности). Еще раз спасибо за объяснения)

Comment: @QuantumNik: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Конечно к вопросу не относится, но с индексами беда: нигде проверяются.

Comment: @Cerbo: Да, но `std::vector` ведёт себя **точно так же**. `v[i]` не проверяет индексы.

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется использовать вложенный прокси класс, который будет имитировать ссылку на объект типа `std::complex`.

Такие прокси-классы используются в определениях стандартных типов таких, как `std::vector<bool>` или `std::bitset`.

Поэтому просто посмотрите самостоятельно, как эти классы реализованы, и на их основе напишите свой прокси-класс.